# Python combine list of dictionaries with an equivalent field

Tags: python, collections, zip, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries in the following form:

```
[
  {
    'author': 'John Doe',
    'book': {
      'name': 'Book 1',
      'year': 1999
    }
  },
  {
    'author': 'Jane Doe',
    'book': {
      'name': 'Book 2',
      'year': 2003
    }
  },
  {
    'author': 'John Doe',
    'book': {
      'name': 'Book 3',
      'year': 2001
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

I would like to combine the objects that have an equivalent `'author'` field to create a list of books, so the result would look like:

```
[
  {
    'author': 'John Doe',
    'book': [{
      'name': 'Book 1',
      'year': 1999
    },
    {
      'name:' 'Book 3',
      'year': 2001
    }]
  },
  {
    'author': 'Jane Doe',
    'book': [{  # a single book should still be a list
      'name': 'Book 2',
      'year': 2003
    }]
  },
  ...
]
```

I can do this just by looping through and storing every object with the same author together, but is there a faster / better way to do this?

Comment: You're data is not well-structured, sometimes `"book"` is `dict`, sometimes it's `list`. Are there any other possible cases?

Comment: By what criteria would another approach be "better"?

Comment: @OlvinRoght sorry, poor formatting. it will always be a dict originally

Comment: @ScottHunter mainly looking for performance optimizations if possible

Comment: @AJwr, `[{"author": k, "books": [i["book"] for i in v] } for k, v in groupby(sorted(o, key=itemgetter("author")), itemgetter("author"))]`. Docs: [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: You will need to loop over your list once. Can't get better than O(n).

Comment: @Wups, I guess you can't get O(n), cause task requires grouping.

Comment: Then "faster/better" is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate a new `dict` with the author name as key. This loops over the list once.

```
authors = {}

for author in lst:
    name = author["author"]
    if name not in authors:
        authors[name] = {"author": name, "books": []}
    authors[name]["books"].append(author["book"])
```

Either you keep it as a dictionary or get the list with `list(authors.values())`

Comment: [Benchmark](https://repl.it/repls/GrumpyUsedRecovery). *(you can add result in answer)*.